# for redirecting the different page on button submit with array to spring Controller()

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

on click on button(submitButton)

create a hidden from  and I have sent the data,
suppose my data is [60,56]

```
     assetGroupId: [60,56]

$("#submitButton").click(function() {
    console.log("submit button is calling");

     var assetID= JSON.stringify(assetGroupId);
document.body.innerHTML += '<form id="assetIdForm" action="http://localhost:9007/abcd" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="assetID" value="assetID"></form>';
document.getElementById("assetIdForm").submit();
```

my controller is:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/abcd", method ={ RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET },produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                                            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getvalue(String[] ID) {
}
```

In my controller i need to get the data is [50,60], but i am getting I,D.
kindly help me.. how i can get data in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<form id="assetIdForm" action="http://localhost:9007/abcd" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="assetID" value="'+assetID+'"></form>';
```

document.getElementById("assetIdForm").submit();

assetID as a variable inside value tag

Answer (score 0):

use name as array  `name="assetID[]"` in html

Comment: in controller is coming null :(